# Медленная работа web-приложения на Android. Почему?

Tags: веб-программирование, android, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Вопрос касается `web` в `Android`. Я разрабатываю приложение на `JavaScript` для мобильных тачфонов. На iPhone все работает превосходно, но вот на `Android` приложение не то, чтобы медленно работало, а работает **очень** медленно! При том, любые графические перерисовки (`DOM`) для него — непосильная ноша.

Кто-нибудь знает, с чем связана такая страшно медленная работа web-приложений в браузере на `Android`? Не думаю, что дело в медленной обработке `JS`, а дело в прорисовке графики страницы. Тем более, что на странице всего-то пару картинок. Остальное CSS и HTML. Меня смущает даже то, что на *iPhone* и на *Android*, установлены браузеры с одним движком — `webkit`.

И еще вопрос: если это можно исправить, то как?

**PS**:  Работа была протестирована на разных телефонах: от средней стоимости до очень дорогих. И в не зависимости от крутых характеристик телефона, если он на `Android`, то работает медленно.

Если это важно, то я делаю приложение на `Sencha Touch`.

Comment: ну с айфоном все понятно - он один, сафари, а вот с андроидами надо смотреть на конфиругацию девайса, на браузер и тд

Comment: Стандартный браузер для Android.
Версия Android 2.2 и выше. И про какую конфигурацию вы говорите?

Comment: девайся, устройства, телефона, я к тому, что если говорить про айфон2 - сразу понятно, проц 2х ядерный А5, а андроид - он сейчас везде, и на телефонах и планшетах от 300уе до 1к

Comment: Может, вы имели ввиду iPad2? Конечно же тогда нужно сравнивать с похожими по характеристикам: Samsung Tab10.1, Asus Transformer... и прочие

Касаемо телефонов аналогично, iPhone 4s - Galaxy S II, Note... и так далее... 

@Антон Мухин, а вы пробовали только стандартный браузер? Его, кажется, до ума начали доводить с версии 3 Андроида. Мне нравится как с JS работает Miren Browser (имхо - лучший), правда только для смартов. К слову, в 4м Андроиде браузер, насколько помню, более-менее до ума довели.

Comment: iPad2 или iPhone 4s... думал про айфон, помнил, что он второй (после iPhone 4).. ну как-то так получилось =) короче, вы меня поняли

Comment: Хм. Мне надо, чтобы минимум версия Андроида была 2.2, и приложение работало на стандартных браузерах. Я так понял из диалога, так это все дело в том, что:   
1. Браузер на Андроиде не очень хорош;    
2. Чтобы нормально работало, надо двухъядерный процессор на телефоне.   
Но что, даже процессор с тактовой частотой в 1 ГГц не помогает?!!

Comment: Здесь, вероятно, проблема в архитектуре самого браузера. Можете дать ссылку для теста?

Comment: Не пробовали на Galaxy Nexus? Говорят, что тесты производительности Javascript на нем значительно лучше чем у iPhone http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2010/07/android-22-demolishes-ios4-in-javascript-benchmarks.ars

Comment: Вот ссылка на пример работы сенчи с официального сайта. Вроде должно работать как надо, но нет... Медленно   
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Comment: @Антон Мухин, Samsung Galaxy S, полет нормальный. Первый раз все грузилось медленно, даже не знаю почему, во второй раз за секунды (как на стационарном компьютере). 

За исключением частых мерцаний при переключении между, например, UserInterfaces, все в пределах нормы. В Miren Browser все заработало сразу без сучка и задоринки, без всяких мерцаний.

Использую Андроид 2.3.6

Comment: Ну так вот дело не в скорости загрузки приложения, а в медленной работе самого приложения. Ну, когда там на кнопки нажимать, прокрутку делать. Это очень простое приложение. Вот когда дело доходит до многофункциональности - тогда все уже плохо. Нарыл какую-то статью, в которой  говорилось о том, что это фишка андроида. Но как-то еще хотел узнать мнение других.

Comment: Так давайте проверим ваш самый простейший "многофункционал"...